# put 2 ul navs into 1 select menu for mobile

Tags: jquery, select, response

I have 2 top nav menus which i would like to combine into 1 select dropdown menu when on mobile.

Using the scripted below only one UL is made into a select menu! dose anyone know away around this or another script to use?

Website is in Wordpress

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('ul#top-nav,ul#trade-menu').mobileMenu({
      switchWidth: 767,                   //width (in px to switch at)
      topOptionText: 'Select a page',     //first option text
      indentString: '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'  //string for indenting nested items
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

User following type of navigation menu for mobile device response :

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/19/responsive-multi-level-menu/

Another one is ;'

http://lukaszfiszer.github.io/selectnav.js/